# How to use pointer to array of structures and access the structure at specific index of an array

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure

Let's have a structure structure_s with elements par1 (int) and par2[] (int array). and in the function we have to at a specific index in structures[m] found out the sumn of par2? How do you do it?

```
int function(struct structure_s *ps){
   //something that determinates index
  
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
   //and now how do I get to the structures[index].par2[j]
    }
}

//the variables n and m are known beforehand
struct structure_s{
   int par1;
   int par2[n];
}

int main(void){
  struct structure_s structures[m];
  int sum = function(structures);
  //etc.
```

Unfortunately, they didn't show this at class and I can't find much useful information.

I have tried using like `(*(ps + index)).par2[j]`, but it doesn't works, it says pointer to undefined type. I also thought maybe when I pass it to function should be &structures, but still the same mistake. Also `(*p)[index].par2[j]` and `(*(p)[index]).par2[j]`, but no idea what to use. Any ideas how to do it?

Edit, SOLUTION: I am stupid, thank you all for the help, it's nice knowing pointers can be noted like arrays and the problem was: not defining struct before function. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: `ps[index].par2[j]` should work just fine. Assuming you define the structure *before* you try to use it...

Comment: However, the `par2` array have the size `n`, and your loop iterates over `m` elements. If `n < m` you have a problem.

Comment: Or you could simply set a temporary pointer to the indexed structure element (`struct structure_s *ptmp = ps + index;`) then use it in your loop (`ptmp->par2[j]`).

Comment: For `ps` a pointer, `*(ps + index)` means exactly the same thing as `ps[index]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int function(struct structure_s *ps){
>    //something that determinates index
>   
>     for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
>    //and now how do I get to the structures[index].par2[j]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> it says pointer to undefined type

Your `structures[index].par2[j]` attempt is well-formed for the structure type you have presented, but you need to have the definition of that type in scope at the point where you use it.  Your example code shows the type definition *after* the function, and if that faithfully reflects your real code then it is the source of the problem.  Make sure the structure definition appears before the function.

In fact, it is fairly conventional to lay out C source files something like this:

1. `#include`s for required headers

   - standard library headers
   - external library headers
   - local headers
2. Local macro definitions not obtained from a header

   - object-like macros
   - function-like macros
3. Local type definitions not obtained from a header
4. File-scope variable definitions, if any (non-definition declarations should come from a header)
5. Any needed forward declarations of local functions not obtained from a header
6. Function definitions

Variations are possible, of course, but that tends to get things in the order you need them.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have `m` elements in your `structures` array and each of them has an `int` array of `n` elements.

This is how you can loop your structure and the arrays inside the items:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //do something with ps[i].par[j]
    }
}
```

I did not declare the variables, I presume they are already declared.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use some composition.

I will show an example below.

Your data is an array of structures, of some size. Each structure has an array inside and is declared

```
struct structure_s
{
    int par1;
    int par2[n];
}
```

For simplicity, let us say that `par1` is the size of array `par2`.

Instead of writing

```
    // the variables n and m are known beforehand
```

and hoping for the best, encapsulate the sizes **INSIDE** each `struct`.

Let us forget the `par[n]` thing. In `C` the size of the array must be known at compile time OR allocated at runtime when the size is determined. To use a variable to declare a size of an array is a thing called **VLA** and it not standard and not widely used except for student's programs.

Consider

```
#define MAX_SIZE 20 // compile time constant

typedef struct
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    int    arr[MAX_SIZE];  // the array;
} Unit;
```

#### the block

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    Unit   U[MAX_SIZE];  // the array;
} Block;
```

And the block is a similar thing, a *container*  of `Unit`

#### Example: create a `Block` and find the maximum value of each `struct`

In the code you see a way to initialize the `struct`s and a program that loop thru them and thru all arrays inside each one, listing the maximum value for each.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 20  // compile time constant
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    int    arr[MAX_SIZE];  // the array;
} Unit;

typedef struct
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    Unit   U[MAX_SIZE];  // the array;
} Block;

int max_value(Block* B, size_t ix);

int main(void)
{
    Unit one = {
        .capacity = MAX_SIZE,
        .size     = 4,
        .arr      = {-1, -2, 0, 1}};

    Unit two = {
        .capacity = MAX_SIZE,
        .size     = 6,
        .arr      = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};

    Block blk = {
        .capacity = MAX_SIZE, .size = 2, .U = {one, two}};
    // now prints the max value of each struct into array
    printf("%llu structs in the array. Max values are:\n", blk.size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < blk.size; i += 1)
        printf("    %llu: %d\n", 1 + i, max_value(&blk, i));
    return 0;
}

int max_value(Block* B, size_t ix)
{
    // get the max value on array inside ix-th struct
    if (B == NULL) return LONG_MIN;
    if (B->size == 0) return LONG_MIN;  // empty
    if (ix > B->size) return LONG_MIN;  // no such position
    int value = B->U[ix].arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < B->U[ix].size; i += 1)
        if (B->U[ix].arr[i] > value)
            value = B->U[ix].arr[i];
    return value;
}
```

#### output

```
2 structs in the array. Max values are:
    1: 1
    2: 6
```